# Ability to distinguish server OpenERP/Odoo version

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

I'm developing mobile app that has to be able work with either 7 and 8 version protocols through raw json rpc requests.
And after few hours of searches I'm still curious, how to determine which version of OpenERP/Odoo server uses?
Any ideas or may be here exists some specific request to know server build info.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**
Thanks to @Mischievous 's answer. It gave me a point.
So, my solution is request like that `your.server.url/web/webclient/version_info`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can find the server info from here. Take look at screen-shot.

Just click on the "About Odoo"

[image]

Comment: Oh, thank you! This is exactly what I looked for.
Sniffer shows me that my solution is request like so your.server.url/web/webclient/version_info

Answer (score 1):

In 7 & 8 just import openerp and it is in openerp.release.version.

You may have to write something yourself that returns this though.

Comment: What do you mean "just import openerp"?
Btw, I can't modify server, because app is just a client and should work with any server by provided URL.

Comment: What I meant was you could write a very simple server method that simply returned the version from openerp.release.version.  However, if you can't modify the server then I'm not aware of anything simple I'm afraid.  You may have resort to some heuristics on the results of a common function like list modules for example.